# How can I fix corrupted text and images (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, display, fonts

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 onto my system and the text and images have been quite blurry - please see the image here:

[image].

Specifics:

1. When I hover my mouse pointer over the text/image, it becomes blurry (if it wasn't already)
2. Recently I had to remount my filesystem (`mount -rw -o remount /`) as part of changing my password. As I booted on, the text/images were allright. On next boot, same problem again.

My computer's configuration:

- Memory - 2.9 GiB
- Processor - Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7300 @ 2.66GHz × 2
- Graphics - Intel® G45/G43
- Disk - 41 GB